# Converting a system model into transition system for model checking

Tags: fsm, model-checking, nusmv, transition-systems

Currently i am trying to convert a system prototype into the transition system model. i have some LTL properties and i want to verify those properties using model checking tool NuSMV. I just information how to start modeling by defining atomoic properties and other mathematical aspects.

[Pictorial Representation of Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AShX3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple encoding in *NuSMV* of that transition system would be

```
MODULE main()
VAR
  state : { GETINFO, ACK, SEND };
ASSIGN
  init(state) := GETINFO;
  next(state) := case
    state = GETINFO : SEND;
    state = SEND    : ACK;
    state = ACK     : {GETINFO, SEND};
  esac;
```

However, i think that the *model* you provided is a bit too simple to match with your *problem description*, thus I invite you to provide additional information about what you intend to do.

Comment: Thanks,Well actually this was my system model where i have to check some LTL properties. this s based on the communication between two parties A and B and some properties to verify is AF (A cannot send information to B) (This problem picture is based on the sender-model of the system)

Comment: oh, ok. I'm used to much more complex models

Comment: Hey Patrick ! i wonder how to merge receiving system model in above mentioned NuSMV source code. in receiver model we have states like {receive information, deliver information and ack}. i want to merge both the model together so that system model looks complex models

Comment: Hi, please edit your question with a complete description of your problem, or open  a new one,  I'll then see if i can update my answer.